# Change order of the meta items on the 4 top posts on the homepage

Tags: html, wordpress, meta

On the homepage of http://hemptoday.net, I want the date to appear before the categories on the top four posts (the ones that display as a vertical list of posts with image thumbnails to the left). Currently, the categories are first, and this is awkward. We run a news site, and the date should display first. I am trying to figure out if I can just add some code in the Custom CSS plugin or if this has to do with html also. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some code samples? You could do this with CSS however a possible, cleaner, easier to read solution would be to reorder your HTML divs.

Comment: `<header class="content-list-header">
  <p class="entry-meta">
<span class="entry-meta-cats"><a href="http://hemptoday.net/food/" rel="category tag">Food</a>, <a href="http://hemptoday.net/legislation/" rel="category tag">Legislation</a>, <a href="http://hemptoday.net/news/" rel="category tag">News</a>, <a href="http://hemptoday.net/north-america/" rel="category tag">North America</a></span>
<span class="entry-meta-date updated">October 28, 2016</span>
</p>` @Turtle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most certainly can´t be solved with css. What css allows you is to change the visuals of html elements. This would need to change the html. Maybe there is a way in the used plugin to change it without accessing the html. Some plugins have settings, where you can set the order of attributes. But what I can say is that it is most certainly not doable just by changing css. My opinion is that it should be done by changing order of elements in html code of the plugin. But as I said, it is hard to tell without any knowledge about the certain plugin and page.